# In what location do assets gain "advertisement" via Rebranding Team?

Tags: android-netrunner

[Rebranding Team](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09006) says

> All assets gain advertisement.

Does it matter where the asset is located? Say, do assets from HQ or Archives also gain "advertisement"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://ancur.fandom.com/wiki/Subtype):

> Cards always have their subtypes, even while inactive.

*Always* means this applies in all zones, including R&D, HQ and Archives

For example: [Rebranding Team](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09006) can be used in conjunction with [Ad Blitz](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09020) to retrieve any Asset from archives.